# Compare return value to EBUSY

Tags: c, pthreads, mutex

So, I'm getting an error on this line of code;

```
else if(lockError == EBUSY)
```

I get the error;

```
use of undeclared identifier 'EBUSY'
```

How do I compare my int lockError to the EBUSY that might be returned when I try a pthread_mutex_unlock.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You forgot to include `#include<errno.h>` where `EBSUY` is defined. See [**errno.h**](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/errno.3.html).

Comment: Thanks. It's been a long day.